# what's the, shall I say, definition of "I admit, I am rather drawn to peel"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Sorry, I didn't remember where I heard it but it was in a series about queen Victoria. her husband says that.
And I guess he was talking about something he liked.

Answer (score 2):

Someone. [Robert Peel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Peel). The transcript from the programme is [here](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=691&t=28972).

Comment: Yes, at various times in 19th century Britain, Sir Robert Peel served as Prime Minister and Home Secretary. He is considered the 'father' of the UK's modern police force and gave his name to an affectionate term for a policeman whom the public often refers to as a 'bobby' (bobbies in plural), as in Sir 'Bobby' Peel. "Peelers" is a more archaic term and had a far less pleasant attribution in Ireland.

Comment: Alternatively he could have been referring to [candied peel](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/candied-citrus-peel);-)